# Buy AppleCare for MacBook Pro in different country than I bought MacBook

Tags: applecare

I bought a MacBook Pro 13" in june 2010 in Poland. I want to buy AppleCare Protection, I'm going to Hong Kong where it is 50% cheaper than in Poland. So can I buy it there? Or are there any law/guarantee restrictions?

Mateusz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I purchased my Applecare from China (while I was living there), my MacBook came from Canada, and now I live in New Zealand, where I can still use my Applecare.

Mobile products (like MacBooks) have a worldwide warranty, and that extends to purchases for Applecare as well. Just make sure you are purchasing from a trustworthy seller and you should be set.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I know of quite a few people based in the UK who have bought their Apple Care from eBay in the states.