# Buying AppleCare for a macbook from a country where it is not officially supported

Tags: warranty, applecare

A number of sources confirm that AppleCare can be bought [any time during warranty](http://www.macworld.com/article/2048197/is-applecare-worth-it-.html) and [even in a different country](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8138/buy-applecare-for-macbook-pro-in-different-country-than-i-bought-macbook?rq=1). In my country (South Africa) apple care is not officially supported, the resellers here say that you have to buy *their* warranty that only covers you locally. However, I plan to travel with my macbook.

Would an istore elsewhere in the world would turn down my request to buy apple care or refuse to honour it specifically because I bought my macbook in a country that does not "have" applecare? I even hear of people buying applecare on Amazon, could I buy online while I'm still in my own country?